# Validation summary won't show when pressing enter key?

Tags: validation, validationsummary

I'm pretty new to programming and this is my first post so please bear with me.

I am trying to validate multiple text boxes when I press enter and display the appropriate validation summary. The form does validate when I press the enter key but the validation summary doesn't update when I change the info and press enter a second time. However, it does update when I press the 'Submit' button.

I am using 2 different validation summaries to show if the user has not entered text or has but the passwords do not match (because I want to use the header text property to display only one message if the user has left an item blank).

I have searched for over an hour on this and the best I could find was this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/sahannet/archive/2011/01/22/asp-net-validation-summary-control-and-enter-key-submit.aspx

but I don't understand how to use that.